# Cancel Button of SearchBar change the Style of StatusBar

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, uisearchbar, statusbar

This is my original screen, I've a custom nav controller with this light Style, and a Search bar to filter my array

[image]

But, when I press the cancel button or when I want dismiss the result of the search, my status bar change to black

[image]

How do I keep the white color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change in `info.plist` the row `View controller-based status bar appearance` and set it to NO